# Multiple rewrite rule not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Well URL rewriting is nightmare and I am having that for many days.
I am trying to rewrite url like:

- `example.com/playground.php?room=abc123` **TO** `example.com/room/abc123`
- `example.com/index.php?room=abc123&action=join` **TO** `example.com/join/abc123`

I am being able to successfully rewrite the first URL (as in the first case) but am not being able to rewrite the second URL properly. It is being rewritten as `example.com/room/join/abc123`. I understand that the first rule is being applied for both cases and then the execution of the htaccess stops. But then how to manage to get the desired solution?

**HTACCESS**

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php !-f
RewriteRule ^room/([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ playground.php?room=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php !-f
RewriteRule ^join/([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ index.php?room=$1&action=join [L]
```

Comment: So the rewrite rules you have shown in your example are working and you want to add two more rules to do what you are asking in your question?

Comment: Only my first rule is working. Second rule gives output like `example.com/room/join/abc123` but I want `example.com/join/abc123`

Comment: second rule gives output `index.php?room=abc123&action=join` and should kick in for `example.com/join/abc123`

Comment: But it isn't. It gives me 404

Comment: `http://example.com/index.php?room=abc123&action=join` works?

Comment: When I get `example.com/room/join/abc123`, if I remove `room` from the url everything is fine. My scenario is something like this: A user clicks a button and he is taken to the url `example.com/room/abc123`. Then that user shares the link to other user, where the other user uses it to join the same room. Depending on the some criteria like if a cookie is present or not he should be taken to `example.com/join/abc123` which is `example.com/index.php?room=abc123&action=join`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142579/discussion-between-thakkie-and-ayan).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is not in the URL rewriting, but it has to do with your `playground.php`. It has relative URLs instead of absolute URLs. Please change `join/abc123` to `/join/abc123`.

Also there is a tiny error in your `.htaccess`

You should change

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php !-f
```

to

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```